# How to protect data leakage from Global declaration in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having one issue ....

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     
        var player1 = function(){
           console.log("Calling player1")
         }
        
        window player2 = function(){
           console.log("Calling player2")
         }
      });
```

In this case if the page is reloaded and I try to access player1 in browser console it shows error message and securing my code...

But if I call player2 it return the function in console and not securing my code... So the users can see the function declaration and all ....

Is there any way to handle this Javascript IIFE in global functions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have error in your code.

It should be like that probably if that is js

```js
  window.player2 = function(){
           console.log("Calling player2")
         }
```

What you want to achive?

Comment: I want to acheive Javascript iife in global variables

Comment: ```(() => window.globalStuff = 'I am declared in global scope')();```